# How can I export the opacity of a mesh per keyframe?

Tags: 3dsmax

I'd like to export opacity of mesh materials on a per-keyframe basis from 3DS Max using a script. How can I accomplish this?

(This is basically extension to my [previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11413/fbx-mesh-animation-opacity-export).)